# Looking for approach to design two classes and one interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, design-patterns

```
public interface ISaveData
{
     void DeleteFile(); // this is common method
     //void ChangeBucket(); I don't need this method in GoogleCloudSaveFile. Should I remove this from here
     // void AssignPermission(); // I don't need of this method in AzureSaveData. Should I remove this from here?
}

public class AzureSaveData : ISaveData
{
     void ChangeBucket()
     {...}

     void DeleteFile()
     {...}
}

public class GoogleCloudSaveFile() : ISaveData
{
     void AssignPermission()
     {...}
     void DeleteFile()
     {...}
}
```

I want to expose Interface to my presentation layer.

How can I design above three classes (2 classes and 1 interface) to expose all methods to my presentation layer.

All methods means:

- Delete()
- ChangeBucket()
- AssignPermission()

**Please ask me if you need more explanation**

Presentation layer could be like

```
void Main()
{
    ISaveData saveFiles = new GoogleCloudSaveFile(); // This is just example. I will inject this via Dependency Injection framework

    saveFiles.Delete(); 
}
```

`ChangeBucket()` and `AssignPermission()` are just example methods. I wanted to say, our child classes could have different methods like these two.

One solution is I can define these two methods in interface and can leave method body empty of one method but I don't think it will be good approach

Comment: I think we need more explanation.  It appears that in your presentation layer, you have class(es) that work with an `ISaveData` object, and you want those classes to be able to call `ChangeBucket()` and `AssignPermission()` because you want to expose those methods to the presentation layer.  But obviously they can't call those two methods if the object is the wrong type.  What's the intent?  Do you have some other mechanism for determining whether an object is the right type, so that you know whether you can call those methods? ...

Comment: I think we need to see more of the picture, and the best answer to your question depends on how this interface will be used.

Comment: Okay let me explain scenario. For example. I want to save file on cloud. My presentation layer don't know which cloud server is using at backend. May be I need to introduce one more interface or abstract class in above design to achieve this. Means need to redesign above solution. I am going to update question. Might be it will help

Comment: If your presentation layer doesn't know which cloud server is being used, why would the presentation layer need to use `ChangeBucket()` or `AssignPermission()`, since those seem to be methods specific to one or the other cloud server?  And if it doesn't need to use those, then you don't need to expose them in the interface.

Comment: I think your method DeleteFile() does not belong in ISaveData, or probably you should change the name of the Interface itself. Also, it seems the ChangeBucket() and AssignPermission methods do not belong to a single interface for that matter. You can use multiple interfaces.

Comment: @ajb - As far as I think, the implementation would be different for each cloud solution.

Comment: Please don't consider methods names. It is confusing. My mistake.

Comment: The implementation of _what_?  That's the important question you need to answer.  If there's some operation that both cloud solutions have, and that operation's implementation uses `ChangeBucket()` in one server and `AssignPermission()` in the other, then _that_'s the operation that should be in the interface.  Then your presentation layer can call that method without having to worry about how it's implemented.

Comment: @ajb - Agree with your last comment. Okay let me ask this from some different angle, Assume google cloud gives extra feature that don't give Azure and I need to implement this in google cloud class then how I achieve this. Should I include this extra method in interface or redesign my solution?

Comment: You can put the common methods which belong together in a common interfaces, and have different interfaces for different functionalities if you wish to use them. like ICloudCommon, IGoogleDriveOperations, IAzureOperations, something like that.

Comment: Take a look at the Interface Segregation Principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and Role/Header Interfaces (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/HeaderInterface.html).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can think based on the information provided by you without getting into the nitty-gritty of what method would lie in which interface, this is the easiest I can think of:

```
public interface ISaveData
{
    void DeleteFile(); // this is common method
}

public interface IPermission
{
    void AssignPermission();
}

public interface IBucketOperation //or something else
{
    void ChangeBucket();
}

public class AzureSaveData : ISaveData, IBucketOperation 
{
    public void ChangeBucket()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AzureSaveData ChangeBucket");
    }

    public void DeleteFile()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AzureSaveData DeleteFile");
    }
}

public class GoogleCloudSaveFile : ISaveData, IPermission
{
    public void AssignPermission()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GoogleCloudSaveFile AssignPermission");
    }

    public void DeleteFile()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GoogleCloudSaveFile DeleteFile");
    }
}
```

You can use these as follows:

```
    ISaveData x = new GoogleCloudSaveFile();
    x.DeleteFile();
    (x as IPermission).AssignPermission();
```

You can also check if the object you create is of the type before typecasting:

```
if(x is IPermission)
    (x as IPermission).AssignPermission();
```

I am not sure if you are willing to take the following approach but I think this would be better:

```
public interface IGoogleCloudSaveFile : ISaveData, IPermission { }
public interface IAzureSaveData : ISaveData, IBucketOperation { }
```

It would be difficult for you to use a common interface and expect it to have different methods available for different type of objects based on the implementation unless you want to ignore design principals and put everything into one interface. In that case, just put everything in one interface, and while implementing it in the classes, just do a

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Comment: ISaveData x = new GoogleCloudSaveFile(); x.AssignPermission(); // I don't think "AssignPermission()" method will be available if I use your approach that you mentioned above. Please correct me if I am wrong. Talking about 2nd line of code "x.AssignPermission();"